# Does Cocoa's CFHost support IDNs?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, dns, idn, punycode

WINAPI has methods to convert Unicode host names to Punycode. Does Cocoa/Cocoa Touch have a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SBPunyCode](https://github.com/blommegard/SBPunyCode) (updated link)

Answer (score 2):

There's a little hack that works without any external libraries. Assuming you have a Unicode URL in *theUrl*, you can do:

```
NSURL *urlToLoad = nil;
NSPasteboard * pasteboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"RandomPB"];
[pasteboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
@try
{
    if ([pasteboard setString:theUrl forType:NSStringPboardType])
        urlToLoad = [WebView URLFromPasteboard:pasteboard];
}
@catch (NSException * exception)
{
    urlToLoad = nil;
    NSLog(@"Can't create URL from string '%@'.", theUrl);
}
return urlToLoad;
```